# how should i batch my data based on a specific column?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

apologies if my question is too simple. i'm not very experienced with ML.
I'm working on a personality prediction Model from social media data, for example facebook statuses or tweets. each person has a unique ID which is included in a column in the dataset. the model should take all entries of a person into account when predicting the personality of that person, instead of analyzing each tweet or status seperately.

i tried giving the ID as an input to the model, but the ID shouldn't influence the training of the model, so i had an overfitting problem. i tried concatenating all the entries of a person together and feeding it to the model, but it creates really long texts and the training was very resource exhaustive. i was thinking of creating batches from the entries of a person, but i don't know how to batch or bucket the data based on the values of a column, also some users have over 50 entries while some have less than 10 entries, so the batches won't be the same length. let me know if you have any ideas on how to handle this. thanks.